# How to implement Kendo Validation inside of a Kendo UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was able to get the kendo validation working perfectly when the inputs were on my page out in the open. But once I moved the inputs into a kendo dialog box, they stopped working. I am submitting these inputs to a kendo grid. The submission works but is now submitting invalid posts and there's no invalid message errors from the kendo validator -- all because i put it inside an #askdialog dialog popup. 
Normally I could just target the SUBMIT button with an id and use that for validation....but there is nowhere to put an id because it's a button built into by the kendo dialog. please help! (FYI, #chd-new-button down below is the first submit button I had on the page. Not the new submit button inside the kendo dialog. Like I said, the new submit button has no id because it's generated by kendo using their lingo which you will see below):

```
//validation for email and phone fields
    var em = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var pho = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;

    var validator = $("#askdialog #new-question-form").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
            validEmail: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name=Email")) {
                    return em.test(input.val().toLowerCase());
                }
                return true;
            },
            validPhone: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name=Phone")) {
                    return pho.test(input.val());
                }
                return true;
            }
        },
        messages: { validEmail: "Please enter a valid email address", validPhone: "Please enter a valid phone number" }
    }).data("kendoValidator");



    var _newInquiry;
    console.log(_newInquiry)
    //post new inquiry to grid
    function submitForm() {
        if (newInquiry) {
            kGrid.dataSource.add(newInquiry);
            kGrid.dataSource.sync();
            console.log(newInquiry);
            _newInquiry = newInquiry.Question;
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
        console.log(_newInquiry);
    };

    //submit button validation and clear form afterwards
    $("#askdialog #chd-new-button").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(_currentUser);
        if (validator.validate()) {
            console.log("good");
            //$('#new-question-form').find('input:text').val('');
            $('textarea').val('');
        } else {
            console.log("bad");
        }
    });
//ask a question dialog popup
    $("#askdialog").kendoDialog({
        open: function () {
            $("#facility").kendoComboBox();
        },
        animation: {
            open: {
                duration: 300
            }
        },
        visible: false,
        width: "500px",
        title: "Ask a Question",
        content: "<div id='new-question-form'>" +
            //"<h5 class='h5'>Ask Your Own</h5>" +
            "<input name='Prefix' id='prefix' placeholder='Prefix' type='text' class='k-textbox' maxlength='50' data-bind='value: Creator.NamePrefix' />" +
            "<input name='First Name' id='firstname' placeholder='First Name (Required)' type='text' class='k-textbox' maxlength='300' data-bind='value: Creator.FirstName' required />" +
            "<input name='Last Name' id='lastname' placeholder='Last Name (Required)' type='text' class='k-textbox' maxlength='300' data-bind='value: Creator.LastName' required />" +
            "<select id=\"facility\" style=\"width:100%;\" id='facility' name='Facility' placeholder='Facility (Required)' data-bind='value: Creator.DMIS' required></select>" +
            "<input name='Email' id='email' placeholder='Email (Required)' type='text' class='k-textbox' maxlength='300' data-bind='value: Creator.Email' required />" +
            "<input name='Phone' id='phone' placeholder='Phone (Required)' type='text' class='k-textbox' maxlength='50' data-bind='value: Creator.Phone' required />" +
            "<input name='DSN' id='dsn' placeholder='DSN' type='text' class='k-textbox' maxlength='50' data-bind='value: Creator.PhoneDSN' />" +
            "<p class='directions separate'>If you have multiple questions, please submit them in separate inquiries.</p><p class='directions caution'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Caution:</span> <span style='font-style: italic;'>Do not include Personally Identifiable Information (PII).</span></p>" +
            "<textarea name='Text' rows='6' placeholder='Enter Question Here' class='k-textbox' data-bind='value: Question' required></textarea>" +
            //"<div id='chdButton'><button id='chd-new-button' type='submit' class='btn btn-green'>Submit</button></div>" +
            "</div>",
        actions: [
            { text: 'Submit', action: submitForm, primary: true }],
        buttonLayout: "stretched"
    }).data("kendoDialog");
```